# Not valid JDK Java Home on Weblogic's installer

Tags: windows-7, installation, jdk

I'm trying to install Weblogic using the [Quick Installer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-main-097127.html).
According to the *README* file I shoudl first set my `JAVA_HOME` system variable.

> QUICKSTART
>
> 1. Setup JAVA_HOME for the target platform.

So, consider this done.

[image]

If run `%JAVA_HOME%` in my terminal I can verify that.

[image]

But when I run the installer it point to the Java Runtime path.

[image]

Why is that ?

Comment: Try running this and see if it works `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java -jar fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls_quick.jar"` (including the quotes).

Comment: @n8te Yeap, so easy, you are right. So how to avoid this ? Do I have to make any adjustments ? Change the `JRE_HOME` or something ?

Comment: It's unclear to me without being able to see some of your other settings why it is trying to run the install from the jre directory instead of the the jdk one. Maybe jre is listed in your %PATH% and that is superseding the JRE_HOME? Just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is unclear why the installer is looking in the jre directory instead of jdk, a simple workaround for installing Weblogic is to simply run this command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java -jar fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls_quick.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables don't propagate changes instantly, they are set once when a process is started and don't change anymore unless the process itself does it.

If you have opened that `cmd` window before setting new `JAVA_HOME`, then it's probably still using the old value. You can check that by running `echo %JAVA_HOME%` in that `cmd`.

If you want to quickly ensure that all env variables are up to date across the system, then just log out from Windows and then log in again. The quicker way would be to run `set JAVA_HOME=<valid_path_here>` in that `cmd`, but it will update it only there and in programs started from that `cmd`.

Comment: I've tried both way you proposed in vain, if you see I echo the correct java home path in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try running from $JAVA_HOME\bin directory.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin>java -jar C:\Weblogic\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_quick_Disk1_1of1\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_quick.jar

It works.

Answer (score 0):

Run this commands

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_XXX
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_XXX\bin;%path%
```

please replace XXX with the version of you java
then you can now run the cmd:

```
java -jar fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls_quick.jar
```

Comment: (1) You say “execute the ff command”, but you don’t show it. (2) What is “the ff command”? (3) Are you saying that it’s *better* to use the `set` command from CMD than to set the environment variables through the control panel GUI? (4) Your example shows concatenating the new path directory and the old path string without a delimiter.

Comment: just to make sure that you will be using your desired java version it is easier to set via command cmd than control panel GUI. and this update is available within the opened cmd window.

Answer (score 0):

Check the if folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath" exist if so:
remove entry "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath" from your PATH env variable. It prevents using your correct JDK instance.